# How can I set current page and current parameters in visualforce expression?

Tags: visualforce, parameters

I have an output link on a vf page. I'd like for users to navigate to the edit page and then be redirected back to the vf page where they came from (which has a parameter in the URL). How can I do that? Thanks.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
<apex:outputLink value="/{!t.id}/e?retURL={!URLFOR('/apex/' + $CurrentPage.Name, null,'param1'= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('param1'))">Edit</apex:outputLink>
```

Comment: Did you try it without the URLFOR()? The parameter retURL should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who's interested, this is the code that worked in the end:

```
<apex:outputLink value="/{!t.id}/e?retURL={!URLFOR('/apex/'+$CurrentPage.Name, null,[param1=$CurrentPage.parameters.param1])}">Edit</apex:outputLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

This [blog](http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-basics-with-returl-saveurl-and-cancelurl.html) helps break down the different parameters that can be used to achieve this...

> The logic behind where the user is redirected on click of the Save
>   button is as follows*:
>
> Is there a saveURL URL parameter set? If so, redirect to that.
>
> Is there a retURL URL parameter set? If so, redirect to that.
>
> Redirect to /home/home.jsp

Comment: Thanks for this blog. It's helpful for organizing the retURL/saveURL which I will also have to figure out. However, my struggle right now is to pass a parameter from the current page into the URL for the retURL on a page the user is redirected to. Do you know how I could do that?